# How do I log out a user in a Rails integration/controller unit test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, devise

I have the following test to ensure sign in is required. Most of the tests require a signed in user, so I have the user sign in on setup. However for this test, I need them signed out.

```
require 'test_helper'

class DealsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  setup do
    @deal = deals(:one)
    @user = users(:one)
    # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara
    @user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    @user.save
    login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
  end

  teardown do
    Warden.test_reset! 
  end

  test "require sign in for deal list" do
    logout @user
    get deals_url
    assert_redirected_to new_user_session_path
  end
```

I get the error

> Failure:
>   DealsControllerTest#test_require_sign_in_for_deal_list [C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/fortuneempire/test/controllers/deals_controller_test.rb:35]:
>   Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>

It says it will work, but it's just not working.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

> If for some reason you need to log out a logged in test user, you can use Warden's logout helper.
>
> logout(:user)

Rails 5.0.2
Devise 4.2.1

Comment: As pointed in the documentation, the method call is `logout(:symbol)`. You are calling it passing a model. I think you need to call it passing a symbol according to the model you want to sign out. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logout` by itself without any parameters worked. Maybe `logout :user` would work too. I wasn't using FactoryGirl so was confusing it for a FactoryGirl symbol.